# How to fix problem with hashing in postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have problem with my project. I am using Postgres database (9.6). In my project I am creating application user object and then hashing his password with BCrypt. After that inserting it into the database. But when I try to log in, hash from database and hash created from credentials are not matching thus I cannot log in. When I tried to connect to another database type (MariaDB) it worked perfectly. I dont know what I am doing wrong, but it has to be some wrong configuration in database connection.

```
//this is my connection configuration
db: {
        hostname: "localhost",
        dialect: "postgres",
        username: "user_turnaj",
        password: "heslo",
        database: "turnajovka",
        logging: false
    }
```

This is how my User object looks

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const hashPassword = password => {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync());
};

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const model = sequelize.define("User", {
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR,
            length: 60,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: user => {
                const hashed = hashPassword(user.password);
                console.log(hashed);
                user.password = hashed;
            }
        }
    });

    model.prototype.hashPassword = function (password) {
        return hashPassword(password);
    };

    model.prototype.validPassword = function (password) { //this is where the hashes are not the same
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    };

    return model;
};
```

This is how table with Users looks like, it was auto generated by my model User.

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table users
(
    id         serial                   not null
        constraint users_pkey
            primary key,
    username   varchar(255)             not null
        constraint users_username_key
            unique,
    name       varchar(255)             not null,
    password   char(255)                not null,
    email      varchar(255)             not null
        constraint users_email_key
            unique,
    gender     enum_users_gender,
    role       enum_users_role default 'USER'::enum_users_role,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone not null
);

alter table users
    owner to user_turnaj;
```

Comment: Please show the SQL statements that create the user and store the password. I assume you don't mean CREATE USER, because BCrypt is not supported as a type of hash for postgres users.

Comment: Yes you are right, I specified my question. I hope I provided enough details now.